# js not setting correct value to div.style.top

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function gamestart(){
    var gr;
    var gr = true;
    console.log(gr==true);
    if(gr == true){
        console.log("we have activated pointer key detection dear Mr.ketsebaot")
        document.onkeydown = checkk;
    }

}

function checkk(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        if(document.getElementById('player-one').getBoundingClientRect().top < 503){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var vertical = document.getElementById('player-one').getBoundingClientRect().top;
            document.getElementById("player-one").style.top = vertical - 0.5 + "px";
            console.log(vertical)
        }
        else{
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var verticalb = document.getElementById('player-one').getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var newv;
        var newv = verticalb+0.5
        console.log("new top value: "+newv)
        document.getElementById("player-one").style.top = newv +"px";
    }
}
```

```css
.player-one{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div className='player-one' id='player-one'></div>

<h1 onClick={gamestart()}>Press to start</h1>
```

i have a question. i have a fucntion written in java script which takes keybored input and checks if the arrow keys are pressed and based on that edits a div named player-one's top and left to move it around

```
function checkk(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        if(document.getElementById('player-one').getBoundingClientRect().top < 503){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var vertical = document.getElementById('player-one').getBoundingClientRect().top;
            document.getElementById("player-one").style.top = vertical - 0.5 + "px";
            console.log(vertical)
        }
        else{
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var verticalb = document.getElementById('player-one').getBoundingClientRect().top;
        console.log(verticalb)
        console.log("0.5")
        var newv;
        var newv = verticalb+0.5
        console.log(newv)
        document.getElementById("player-one").style.top = newv +"px";
        console.log(newv)
    }
}
```

But it seems like it is not working and the problem is for both subtracting and adding 0.5 the top value seems to be always increaseing no matter what.

here is my css for player-one

```
.player-one{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

i tryied to increase the style.top of a div whenever a key was clicked(arrow down) and deacrease it when another key was clicked(arrow up), but what happend was it increased for the first key(up) and also increased for the second key(down key)?

Comment: `.player-one` in your css is a class sector, where you have `player-one` as an id.

Comment: i both have it as a class selector and id selector at the same time

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: ok added it but now it seems like it is subracting and adding properly but only ones so the value keeps on flactuating between two values

Comment: To move it i think it needs to be position: absolute

Comment: it does move in both position: relative and position absolute! but always down it never goes up

Comment: try this: https://gist.github.com/JsThiago/8f5913190b94903f785a4105f393c805

Comment: tryied it, it still moves down for both

Answer (score -1):

A couple of things:

Your css shows ".player-one" which is a class selector, not an ID one. As above, make sure you use "#player-one { css here }".

Last but not least, to avoid so much typing, you should save element selection in a const and use the const in your code. In your case it would be:

```
const playerOneEl = document.getElementById("player-one");
```

And then you'd write

```
playerOneEl.style.top = `${newv}px`
```

(look up template literals)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: i apologies for my repeatative writing and for making a mess with the code but the problem dosent seem to be with selecting the player rather with setting its style.top to newv

Comment: `document.getElementById("#player-one")` finds the element with `<div id="#player-one">`, not `<div id="player-one">`. You provably meant `document.querySelector("#player-one")`